# Use service function in directive in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, coffeescript, angularjs-service

I want to call service function from directive's controller. The service name is **Auth** and function name is **Auth.logout**. I already injected service in directive's controller but not working. Please let me know What should I do ? The script is written in coffeescript.

Directive code :-

```
class GlobalNav extends BaseDirective
  @register 'globalNav', ->
    restrict: "E"
    templateUrl: 'templates/Directives/global-nav.jade'

    controller: ($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate, $ionicPopup,Auth) ->
      $scope.closeSideMenu = ->
        $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft(false)
      $scope.showConfirm = ->
        confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm(
          title: 'Message'
          template: 'Are you sure you want to logout?')
        confirmPopup.then (res) ->
          if res
            Auth.logout <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< This is not called
          return
        return
```

Auth service code :-

```
class Auth extends BaseService
  @register 'Auth'

  AUTH_KEY: 'userAuth'
  AUTH_REJECTION: 'authentication'

  constructor: (@$q, @$http, @$rootScope, @$cordovaFacebook, @storage, @Api, @$track, @FacebookAuth) ->

  authenticated: -> !_.isEmpty(@_getAuth())

  logout: ->
    q = @$q.defer()
    @storage.clearAll()
    @_auth = null
    @Api.expireGlobalCache()
    @$cordovaFacebook.logout().then(q.resolve)
    q.promise
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After translating to JavaScript, it turns out that you don't call `Auth.logout()`, but only evaluate `Auth.logout` (without applying the `()` operator).